# The problem with the correct use of a rigid body in a 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I decided to make a 2D game for the PC on Unity, where the character moves around the stage. But I have a problem with the correct use of Rigid Body 2D.

In this picture you can see my playing field.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBhwx.png

I want my character to move around the entire field and when colliding with objects does not go through them.

My field is Tilemap, but I hung the Box Collider on the Grid. Boxing collider surrounds the grid.

But when I use Rigid Body and turn on the game, the object falls through. And if you remove the Rigid Body, then it just goes through objects.

I tried to use different types of Rigid Body, when using kinematic and static, sprite goes through houses.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is when you attach a RigidBody2D to an object, you give it physics properties, but it won't do anything useful without a collider. If you have an object with collider attached - every other object with collider attached will collide with it.

In your case the player should have RigidBody2D and BoxCollider2D. The ground should have BoxCollider2D, and basically everything you want the player to collide with should have BoxCollider2D. So the houses should have BoxCollider2D as well.
This setup should allow the player to walk on the ground without falling through it, and collider with houses.

Make sure that the collider's area is correct. You can preview it in the editor and edit it if it's not correct.

Also if you want it to work make sure the camera points down and your game setup is alongside Y axis so if there's a rigid body object falling down it falls down on the ground not before/behind it.